# LNK2019 and LNK1120 with functions in an external file

Tags: c++, linker, linker-errors, lnk2019

I have taken out some functions from a source file into another since I want to use them also in other files. The current structure is as follows

`utils/extFuncs.h`

```
#ifndef _extFuncs_h
#define _extFuncs_h
inline int someFunction (float v);
#endif
```

`utils/extFuncs.cpp`

```
#include "utils/extFuncs.h"
inline int someFunction (float v) {
    return 42;
}
```

`foo/bar.h`

```
#ifndef _bar_h
#define _bar_h
#include "utils/extFuncs.h"
class Bar {
public:
    Bar (float x);
};
#endif
```

`foo/bar.cpp`

```
#include "foo/bar.h"
Bar::Bar (float x) {
    int y = someFunction(x);
}
```

Problem is, that when I try to compile this, the linker complains and says that the symbol `someFunction` could not be resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`someFunction` is declared `inline`, so it *must* be defined in your header file:

```
utils/extFuncs.h

#ifndef _extFuncs_h
#define _extFuncs_h
inline int someFunction (float v)
{
    return 42;
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add the extFunction.h & extFunction.cpp into your project workspace?

Comment: everything is in the same solution, however in different subfolders.